# Online orthodox conversion

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, internet, orthodox

Is it acceptable to trust the legitimacy of an online Orthodox conversion program provided by studyjudaism.net?

Comment: Looks promising, but from your point of view, you are asking one set of strangers to vet another set of strangers, on something that involves a huge decision, so I don't think this site can cater to this, sorry. Try and find your nearest orthodox Rabbi and get in touch - that's the usual way a propective convert should get started, all the best!

Comment: Welcome! Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi. This post will likely be closed as "off-topic." You can learn more about crafting a question from the help center: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/

Comment: This question was asking about the website not necessarily for their individual circumstances @RabbiKaii

Comment: See the original version of the question and if it isn't closed on those grounds it would still be off topic as it's not our job to vet organisations generally

Comment: I could see maybe starting the learning process online, but I can’t imagine any Orthodox rabbi completing a conversion where the potential convert does not live in an Orthodox Jewish community.

Comment: @ezra I was on-track to do just that while I was in the Army. Study in Kansas with a 'rabbi' who was teaching Noahides online for x amount of time, then eventually fly to NY for the formal conversion under a supervising rabbi for only $4000. Fly back a Jew. As I learned more, it started to sound 'fishy', so I contacted the rabbi of the synagogue my teacher attended. Turned out my teacher wasn't really a rabbi and the whole thing fell apart. But it likely would have resulted in an Orthodox conversion, had I not asked so many questions.